# Designing a Manipulate Block

Tags: graphics, list-manipulation, design-patterns, column, row

I am trying to create a Manipulate block which contains tabels, graphs and explanations.
In the first row I want to add some tables and explanations, but sometimes the tabels are cut. For doing this I am using `GraphicsRow` with  a list of the elements to show. The problem is that the larger elements are being cut while the smaller ones have spaces.
I have tried to change the `ImageSize` and nothing solved it.
How can I control the space for each cell in `GraphicsRow` ? Is there a way to design my block in some kind of GUI mode ?

The Code:
[image]

The Relevant Output:
[image]

Is there a more efficient way to design the block ? Any help will be appreciated!
 Thank you

Comment: Greetings! Make the most of Mma.SE and **take the [tour] now**. **Help us to help you**, write an [excellent question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). [Edit](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) if improvable, show due diligence, give brief context, include **minimal** working examples of **code and data in [formatted form](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help)**. As you receive **give back**, vote and answer questions, keep the site useful, be kind, correct mistakes and share what you have learned.

Comment: Here its considered helpful to show your own efforts and share  a minimum working example of your code in a **[well formatted form](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) instead of images** or links to external files, so we can quickly **Copy&Paste** your code, test it, and  see the problem you are facing. Please help us to help you and [edit your question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) accordingly. This [question in Meta](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2/how-should-i-include-code-samples-in-posts) could be useful.

Comment: You can use `Pane/Frame/Panel` with `ImageSize` to control the size. And I'd say that `Grid` is better unless you only have graphics there.